# Grails app can't connect to mysql service

Tags: mysql, grails, cloud-foundry

My grails 2.1.0 application was deployed and working in cloudfoundry, using the mysql service, yesterday I made some changes and after updating can't get it to work again. I've made no changes in datasource.

By looking at tomcat logs, it looks like the database settings are not beeing overriden on deploy, [as stated in the documentation](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/services/mysql/grails-mysql.html) , and there's a exception with the message "Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE'".

I'm using Spring Groovy/Grails Tool Suite integration to deploy my application to cloudfoundry.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: My first ques would be the "h2" part of the connect url : 'jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE h2 would suggest to me it's trying to connect to the h2 in-memory database as opposed to mysql.

Comment: did you bind a mysql service to your app? can you share the datasource.groovy here? seems you have configured some connection URL that was not matched with mysql

Comment: Just found that a conflict in my svn repo had disabled the cloudfoundry plugin that overrides the datasource definition on deploy to the bound mysql service on cloudfoundry.

The JDBC URL is overriden by the plugin on deploy so when it's working correctly it doesn't matter that the URL does not match the mysql database that your application will use, in fact you can remove the URL altogether that still the mysql service bound to the deployed application will be used. Thanks

Comment: @otonjr convert your comment to an answer and accept it so others don't waste time fixing a fixed problem

Comment: @BurtBeckwith done, tried to do it yesterday, but couldn't since I'm a new user I had to wait 8 hours before posting a answer to my own question. Thanks for the pointer, anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the time folks, just found that a conflict in svn had disabled the cloudfoundry plugin that overrides the datasource definition on deploy to the bound mysql service on cloudfoundry.

The JDBC URL is overriden by the plugin on deploy so when it's working correctly it doesn't matter that the URL does not match the mysql database that your application will use, in fact you can remove the URL altogether